# Getting Error While running dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: java

> A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AdjunctConnectionWSFax]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:851)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AdjunctConnectionWSFax]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint
>   violation: loader (instance of
>   org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated
>   loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletConfig"
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:894)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1298)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1175)
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5058)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Jan 29, 2016 11:10:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:851)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Jan 29, 2016 11:10:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8025]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more

Comment: Posting whole errors here is not use full. Here you suppose to post the context of it if you expect any help from others.

Comment: Actually I want to create two similar projects with same folder structure but different logic so i copied a web project which is running fine and created another with different name and context path but getting above exception while running...plz help

Comment: which server you are using for this

Comment: I am using tomcat8 server...sorry m asking silly question but what u mean by context?? n thanx fo helping

Comment: May be cause of conflicting jar(s) or xml file. Mention which technologies are you using.

Comment: This question is off-topic as you have provided no code or other useful information.  There's nothing on which to base an answer of any kind at this point.

Comment: Thanx @Jim  for help...resolved it by removing duplicate jars from build path and adding server runtime library in build path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn to read exception messages.  Buried in the wall of text is

> loader constraint violation: loader (...) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletConfig

You have two copies of `ServletConfig` in two separate jar files being loaded by different class loaders.  Remove one of the jar files.